# Permission Denied ERROR opening an Excel File using oplrun CPLEX

Tags: excel, permission-denied, cplex

while reading EXCEL file through oplrun (CPLEX) software 'permission denied error' is shown.

what may be the possible reasons of error?

Answer (score 0):

It is usually may be your MS Excel(2013) is not Activated.
So by uninstalling it & installing registered MS Office problem can be resolved.